# The archetype for appfuse is not configured and the build fails

Tags: appfuse

I am running AppFuse from the command line.  I have Maven 3.2.1 and Java 1.7 installed.  I am getting the error: archtype not configured.  I am a bit surprised because I am using the commands from the appfuse website.

Here is the command I am using:

```
mvn -e  archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.5.0 -DgroupId=net.novogrodsky -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

Here is more detail and the error trace:

```
mvn -e  archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.5.0 -DgroupId=net.novogrodsky -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO] Archetype defined by properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.989 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-13T14:20:33-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/164M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The archetype is not configured -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The archetype is not configured
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The archetype is not configured
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeNotConfigured: The archetype is not configured
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:168)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of the Archetype plugin. Can you try "mvn -U archetype:generate" and see if it downloads a new version?

Answer (score 0):

Running "mnv -U archetype:generate" updated the Archetype plugin.  After that, everything worked.